# How to normalize features in a specific dimension of a 3D array with respect to their own type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, normalization

I have a 3D array (1883,100,68) as (batch,step,features).

The 68 features are totally different features such as energy and mfcc.

I wish to normalize the features respective to their own type.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], -1)).reshape(X_test.shape)
print(X_train.shape)
print(max(X_train[0][0]))
print(min(X_train[0][0]))
```

Apparently, turning it into a 2D array won't work because each feature is normalized with respect to all the 6800 features. This caused multiple features from **all** the 100 steps to become zeros.

What I am looking for example, feature[0] is energy. For a batch, there are 100 energy values due to the 100 steps. I wish these 100 energy values normalized within themselves.

So the normalization should be carried out among [1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0]...[1,100,0]. Same for all other features.

How should I approach it?

Update:

The following codes were produced with help from sai.

```
def feature_normalization(x):
    batches_unrolled = np.expand_dims(np.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2])), axis=0)

    x_normalized = (x - np.mean(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)) / np.std(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    np.testing.assert_allclose(x_normalized[0, :, 0], (x[0, :, 0] - np.mean(x[:, :, 0])) / np.std(x[:, :, 0]))
    return x_normalized

def testset_normalization(X_train,X_test):
    batches_unrolled = np.expand_dims(np.reshape(X_train, (-1, x.shape[2])), axis=0)
    fitted_mean = np.mean(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    fitted_std = np.std(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    X_test_normalized = (X_test - fitted_mean) / fitted_std
    return X_test_normalized
```

Comment: Should it be `reshape(-1, X_train.shape[-1])`?

Comment: both ways caused the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To normalize features independently across all the samples in a batch-

1. Unroll batch samples to get [10(time steps)*batch_size] x [40 features] matrix
2. Get the mean and standard deviations of every feature
3. Perform an element wise normalization on the actual batched samples

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((20, 10, 40))

batches_unrolled = np.expand_dims(np.reshape(x, (-1, 40)), axis=0)

x_normalized = (x - np.mean(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)) / np.std(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)

np.testing.assert_allclose(x_normalized[0, :, 0], (x[0, :, 0] - np.mean(x[:, :, 0])) / np.std(x[:, :, 0]))
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Actually, I just realized that it should not be confined to each batch when we do normalization, it should include all the batches and their 100 steps but the features are supposed to normalize independently. Would you mind to modify your codes to include all the batches?

Comment: @Leo, You are correct in realizing that. Additionally, normalization should also not be limited to a certain batch unless you are working with data which has **uniform distribution**. Normalization should be usually same for the entire dataset you are working with

Comment: if I wish to confine the value of x to [-1,1]. Shall i perform  x_normalized = (x-np.min(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)) / (np.max(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)-np.min(batches_unrolled, axis=1, keepdims=True)) ?
 In addition, I have to tweak the codes a bit to make it suitable for normalizing the X_test, right?

Comment: I have updated the question, would you mind taking a look at the codes?

Comment: Unrolling a batch is very much possible, your division operation is happening across a different axis, you will have to check that for yourself. The code mentioned in my answer works and is tested. I would suggest you print the shapes of the matrices and cross check with what you're expecting.#